# SQL Syntax in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to understand why in C# if you have a sql string why you would have to put tick (') marks in the following where clause in order for this to work.  Could someone please explain the reasoning behind this?

```
where ProgramServer='" + machineName.ToString() + "' and Active=1;
```

Comment: can you show the surrounding code? Is this a substring of a larger string? The single ticks are TSQL string deliminators

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid those tick (`'`) marks and use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), They will also save you from [SQL Injection.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

The reason you see those ticks are because SQL expects string type values to be enclosed in single ticks.

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is a dynamically built SQL query in the code. When querying based on a string value, the string must be wrapped in single quotes. The final SQL string would look something like:

```
select * from someTable where ProgramServer = 'YourMachineName' and Active = 1;
```

Unfortunately, that is far from the best way to do things. You should be using parameterized queries instead:

```
var query = "select * from someTable where ProgramServer = @machineName and Active = 1;";
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    command.Parameters.Add("machineName", machineName.ToString());
    // Execute and get the results
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The problem I am having is that machineName is a variable defined within string machineName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();  I'm not sure how to make that work when machineName is not in the table as a column, ProgramServer is.  I need to pull the machine name the console app will be running on

Comment: To explain further, ProgId will store all the currently running defined apps by machine name.  That is why I need to grab the machine name for the application.